# Get Active Directory user information

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Is there a way to retrieve the users active directory information like ad groups, SID and so on?

Currently I could find only examples with active directory azure.

At the moment I catch user information the following way:

```
IReadOnlyList<User> users = await User.FindAllAsync(UserType.LocalUser);
foreach (User user in users)
{
    string displayName = (string)await user.GetPropertyAsync(KnownUserProperties.DisplayName);
}
```

Also the Win10 SDK doesn't provide any examples regarding active directory.

[Edit] There is a WinRT Api request on https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/12556779-get-active-directory-user-information

[Edit] Regarding Issue on corefx https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/7325

Comment: I don't know if this works with azure and all of that. But with Windows 7/8(.1) I always used `WindowsIdentity currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(); var groups = currentUser.Groups;` you would need `using System.Security.Principal;`

Comment: Why the Azure tag?  This question (as is) doesn't apply to Azure.  Please remove or clarify.

Comment: There is a official [User information sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/UserInfo), see if this sample helpful is to you, or do you want to do something with users and azure together, for example push different notifications to different user groups?

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT In .NET 4.5 I would have done, to get the currents user active diretory groups/sids `System.Security.Principal. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() as ClaimsIdentity;` With the mentioned SDK example I can't get this informations. Or am I wrong?

Comment: As I know, there is no available LDAP/AD API in WinRT app, we can configure an app to authorize with [Azure Active Directory](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory).

Answer (score 0):

From command line you can use `whoami /groups`.

From C# you can check membership in a group using the SID using something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace ADMembership
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = new
                WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent());
            String groupName = "A Group";
            SecurityIdentifier sid = new SecurityIdentifier(
                "S-1-1-22-999999999-999999999-999999999-4444");

            if (myPrincipal.IsInRole(groupName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is in {1}.",
                    myPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString(), groupName);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in {1}.",
                    myPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString(), groupName);
            }

            if (myPrincipal.IsInRole(sid))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} has SID: {1}.",
                    myPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString(), sid);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} does not have SID {1}.",
                    myPrincipal.Identity.Name.ToString(), sid);
            }
        }
    }
}
```